# File upload progress Custom page RestAPI SPO

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online, office365api

The code below is working fine to upload files to SPO through RestAPI. No feedback is received on file upload progress. An alert is thrown once the upload is complete.

I would like to have a progress bar to display the upload percentage and reload this upload page while clicking OK to the successful alert message.

Kindly assist.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    init();   
});
function init(){
    $("#btnUploadFiles").click(function(){
        var files=$("#inputTypeFiles")[0].files;
        uploadFiles(files[0]); // uploading singe file
    });
}
function uploadFiles (uploadFileObj) {
    var fileName = uploadFileObj.name;
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var documentLibrary="TEST";
    var folderName = "";
    var targetUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/" + documentLibrary + "/" + folderName;
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@target)/Files/add(overwrite=true, url='" + fileName + "')?$expand=ListItemAllFields&@target='" + targetUrl + "'";
 
    uploadFileToFolder(uploadFileObj, url, function (data) {
        var file = data.d;
        var updateObject = {
            __metadata: {
                type: file.ListItemAllFields.__metadata.type
            },
            departname: $("#departname").val(),   //meta data column1
            Filename: $("#filename").val(),    //meta data column2
            ACFTREG: $("#ACFTREG").val(),    //meta data column3
            Date: $("#datepicker").val()    //meta data column4
        };
        url = webUrl + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('"+documentLibrary+"')/items(" + file.ListItemAllFields.Id + ")";
        updateFileMetadata(url, updateObject, file, function (data) {
            alert("File uploaded & metadata updation done successfully");
        }, function (data) {
            alert("File upload done but metadata updating FAILED");
        });
    }, function (data) {
        alert("File uploading and metadata updating FAILED");
    });
}
 
function getFileBuffer(uploadFile) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(uploadFile);
    return deferred.promise();
}
 
function uploadFileToFolder(fileObj, url, success, failure) {
    var apiUrl = url;
    var getFile = getFileBuffer(fileObj);
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
 
function updateFileMetadata(apiUrl, updateObject, file, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(updateObject),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-Http-Method": "MERGE",
            "IF-MATCH": file.ListItemAllFields.__metadata.etag,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getItems);
function getItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('L%20-%20MDB%20-%20ACFTREG')/items?$Select=Title&$top=2000",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application / json;odata = verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var results = data.d.results;
            var options = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                options = options + "<option value='" + results[i].Title + "'>" + results[i].Title + "</option>";
            }
            $("#ACFTREG").append(options);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}

$( function() {$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
    {
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    }
    );} );
  
</script>


Select File:<input type="File" id="inputTypeFiles" /><br />
Departname: <input id="departname" type="textbox"/><br />
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="hidden"><br />
Filename: <input id="filename" type="textbox"/><br />
ACFTREG: <select id="ACFTREG" class="select">
<option selected="selected">Select</option><br />
<input type="button" id="btnUploadFiles" value="Upload"/><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `$.ajax({})` function, you can add the `xhr` setting inside the ajax.

```
$.ajax({
xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
            // Place upload progress bar visibility code here
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
},
type: 'POST',
//add the rest of ajax settings
```

check this link for ajax documentation
[jQuery/ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

check this link for example on upload progress
[jQuery-upload-progress/example](https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/get-file-upload-progress-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Appreciate the assistance. Im quite new to this, could you kindly amend my code with the answer?

Comment: in the function `uploadFileToFolder` before any options you add in the `$.ajax({})` add the `xhr` option as I described previously in my answer, then replace the line of code that says `// Place upload progress bar visibility code here` with a function you call to view the percentage of the upload process. I hope this is informative enough for you.